# Error 404 when trying to deploy react.js website on to github

Tags: reactjs, git, github

I am trying to deploy my application into Github, I manage to deploy it but I have encountered a problem that is  `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404`.

[image]

As you can see that the web manage to deploy, but all the picture/images are not appearing on my website
https://github.com/stevenleesf/UOWMReact << github
https://stevenleesf.github.io/UOWMReact/ << website

Answer (score 1):

Wrong link, your image is at

https://stevenleesf.github.io/UOWMReact/images/Logo-WHITE.png

not

https://stevenleesf.github.io/images/Logo-WHITE.png

Which is what you are trying to access:

[image: Network tab]

Comment: sorry i am still quite new to github, lets say I made the changes as you state above. how do I update my file into github. by using git push?

Comment: @LeeSoonFatt first a git commit, which creates a "new version" of your page. Then git push.

Comment: after commit and push into my Github. why is my server still running from my previous version, not on the recent version that I push?

Comment: On your github says your last push was 2hrs ago: https://github.com/stevenleesf/UOWMReact

And your website is now showing your readMe. It seems like you made a mistake somewhere. But that seems unrelated to this question. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your reference to the images path is missing the UOWMReact directory before images. See the path for your stylesheet below.

[image]